# do while loop in php

Tags: php

working on a simple counter program

when button is pressed it adds 1
when other button is pressed it minuses 1

once variable reaches 10, i need it to set the  variable to zero

i'm completely new to php, but i know c++, and in c++ i'd do a do-while loop for this

suggestions?

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['number'] = ((isset($_SESSION['number'])) ? $_SESSION['number'] : 0); 
if(isset($_GET['add'])){ 
$_SESSION['number']++; 
} 
if(isset($_GET['minus']))
{
    $_SESSION['number']--;
}
?> 
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get"> 
<input type="submit" style = "width:100px; height: 100px;"  name="add" value="add" />        <br><br>
<input type="submit" style = "width:100px; height: 100px; " name = "minus"     value="minus" />
</form> 
<? 
echo $_SESSION['number']; 
?>
```

Comment: I don't think you would need a `while` loop. You would just check to see when `$_SESSION['number']` reaches 10 with an `if` statement and then set the variable to 0.

Comment: Never use short tag `<?  ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is triggered for each request by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use:

```
if ($_SESSION['number'] == 10) {
  $_SESSION['number'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement do while in php also 
[check this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/dowhile.php)